# How can I generate randomness with commands in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is the most efficient way to get a random output with my commands? In Java there are tons of ways to do this, but a lot of them don’t seem to work for Bedrock Edition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@r` is an obsolete method. It is really only effective for up to 10 outputs.

The standard way to get a random output in Bedrock Edition is `/scoreboard players random`, an MCBE only command.

Syntax:

```
scoreboard players random <player: target> <objective: string> <min: int> <max: int>
```

This will set a scoreboard number to a random value between `min` and `max`.

Answer (score 3):

## Concept

The `@r` selector can be used to pick a random player. What some people do not know, though, is that if you specify another type other than player you can have it select things other than players.

## Commands

Lets say I want to have my machine output white or black wool. We have 2 command blocks with a tick delay of 7 (if we don’t have a tick delay it will sometimes fail) with the command:

```
setblock ~ ~1 ~ air
```

Now chains attached to them with these (one will be white, one black):

```
setblock 5 5 5 wool 0
```

and

```
setblock 5 5 5 wool 14
```

Now above the original impulse command have air and a block above that bedrock with armor stands on top of each. Name the armor stands the same thing. I will use `test`.
Now somewhere else have a command block that says:

```
execute @r[type=armor_stand,name=“test”] ~ ~ ~ setblock ~ ~-2 ~ redstone_block
```

Now when that command block is activated, it will place either a white or black wool block at 5, 5, 5!