# can you make random items drop from random blocks?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

how do I make a random Item drop from a random block. Is it /execute {blocks:"minecraft:stone"} summon Item [name=coal] or is it super long or can I not do It (on xbox)

Comment: Do you want an item to drop when broken with an appropriate tool(you would need an add on for this)?  Or when the block is broken in any way(commands could accomplish this)?

Comment: the "randomizer" gamemode you probably got this idea from is in datapack form

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a dropper that shoots an item/block when a [`/testfor @e[type=item,name="Item Name",c=1]`](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376567/258509) returns true.

Then have a command block that waits say `5` ticks to fire that teleports the dropped item (`/tp @e[type=item,r=3,name="Alternate Item"] @e[type=item,name="Item Name",c=1]`) and after that `/kill @e[type=item,name="Item Name",c=1]` the first item.

You can use [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/377357/258509) method for randomization once you've got the basics set up.